# Routes through centroids and array functions

Tags: postgis, postgresql, route, centroids, array

I have a table stopcentroids4 like in figure with the following fields: gid, routes, geom [image: Input table]

and i want to draw a line for each route that runs through centroids. In my code there is a mistake. Actually the centroid on the lowest and right point of the picutre (where you can read the associated routes 47,57,76A, 92C) becomes the starting point of the routes 2,5,6,7.
[image: Example of the output of the route "2" that includes the wrong centroid, the lowest and right point of the picture]

The postresql code follows below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION walk_centers(bigint, text)   RETURNS geometry AS $BODY$ WITH RECURSIVE next_stop(geom, idlist) AS (
                 (SELECT geom AS geom,
                    ARRAY[gid] AS idlist
                   FROM stopcentroids4
                  WHERE gid = $1)
        UNION ALL
                ( SELECT s.geom AS geom,
                    array_append(n.idlist, s.gid) AS idlist
                   FROM stopcentroids4 s,
                    next_stop n
                  WHERE string_to_array(s.routes,',') @> ARRAY[$2] 
                  AND NOT n.idlist @> ARRAY[s.gid]
                  ORDER BY st_distance(n.geom, s.geom) ASC
                 LIMIT 1)
        )  SELECT ST_MakeLine(geom) AS geom FROM next_stop; 
        $BODY$   
        LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE   COST 100; 
        ALTER FUNCTION walk_centers(bigint, text)   OWNER TO postgres;

This is my code:


CREATE TABLE lines AS
-- Distinct route identifiers! WITH routes AS (   SELECT DISTINCT unnest(string_to_array(routes,',')) AS route   FROM stopcentroids4 ORDER BY route ),
-- Joined back to stops! Every route has all its stops! stops AS (   SELECT s.gid, s.geom, r.route   FROM routes r   JOIN stopcentroids4 s  ON (strpos(s.routes, r.route) <> 0) ),
-- Collects stops by routes and calculate centroid! centers AS (   SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(geom)) AS geom, route   FROM stops   GROUP BY route ),
-- Calculate stop/center distance for each stop in each route. stops_distance AS (   SELECT s.*, ST_Distance(s.geom, c.geom) AS distance   FROM stops s JOIN centers c   ON (s.route = c.route)   ORDER BY route, distance DESC ),
-- Filter out just the furthest stop/center pairs. CREATE TABLE brighton_lines AS
-- Distinct route identifiers! WITH routes AS (   SELECT DISTINCT unnest(string_to_array(routes,',')) AS route   FROM stopcentroids4 ORDER BY route ),
-- Joined back to stops! Every route has all its stops! stops AS (   SELECT s.gid, s.geom, r.route   FROM routes r   JOIN stopcentroids4 s  ON (strpos(s.routes, r.route) <> 0) ),
-- Collects stops by routes and calculate centroid! centers AS (   SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(geom)) AS geom, route   FROM stops   GROUP BY route ),
-- Calculate stop/center distance for each stop in each route. stops_distance AS (   SELECT s.*, ST_Distance(s.geom, c.geom) AS distance   FROM stops s JOIN centers c   ON (s.route = c.route)   ORDER BY route, distance DESC ),
-- Filter out just the furthest stop/center pairs. first_stops AS (   SELECT DISTINCT ON (route) stops_distance.*   FROM stops_distance )
-- Pass the route/stop information into the linear route generation function! SELECT   row_number() over () AS gid, -- QGIS likes numeric primary keys   route,   walk_centers(gid, route) AS geom FROM first_stops;

-- Do some housekeeping too ALTER TABLE lines ADD PRIMARY KEY (gid);
```

Maybe the problem is in the function included in the join: "strpos(s.routes, r.route) <> 0"
and i should replace the regular function "string_to_array" but I'm getting syntax errors.

Comment: I converted your block quote into a code block. Next step: please manually reformat the code so we don't have to do any scrolling to read each line. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you John, I tried to copy the code above erasing comments but i get the result that my code is too much long for a comment